# Alter \temporal command behaviour in the handout mode

Tags: beamer, overlays, handout

I see that using the `\temporal` command, I can put three different texts on slides.

So if I write:

`\temporal<2>{First}{Second}{End}`,

the last word (*End*) will appear in all the slides after the second in the standar Beamer mode with all the slices and their adequate order.
But in handout mode, what will appear is the *default text*, following Beamer Manual nomenclature. In the previous code, *Second* word.

Is there any way to force the command `\temporal` to show the third option instead?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty hack:

```
\documentclass[
  handout
]{beamer}

\mode<handout>{
  \protected\long\def\temporal<#1>#2#3#4{#4}
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \temporal<2>{First}{Second}{End}
  
  \only<3>{test}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```